# How can I have a notification popup when there is a new item in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I would like a pop up message like a notification to come up when a new item is added to a list.  Something similar like outlook does when you get a new email.

So for instance our support team is working on something and when a user logs a fault it automatically displays a popup message. I know I need the following to get this started:

1. A list preferable a view that only shows current items
2. I'd plug to the list via web services so that I can use it in all the page
3. Jquery plugin(But stil looking for one)
4. What do I need to do to push the message without user intervention.

Any ideas and thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a view with specific params to show only required items

2.1 You can create a web part, that will be place on the page with view and check for notifications, but it will not have UI and this web part will connect to your web service

2.2 You can check auto update settings for view, thus new items will be updated automatically

2.3 You can add Content Editor web part with js code you've created.

3.Don't understand what for you are looking for a plugin

4.You can use Client Object Model for JS and method SP.UI.Notify.addNotification - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658473.aspx

Comment: Thanks default.
I haven't used the SPUINotify before.So i was thinking of using Jquery for this.Like a showMessage plugin.
Do u have more  resources for SP.UI.Notify.addNotification?

Comment: the easiest - http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Robin/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=119 and more complex http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/02/25/how-to-sharepoint-2010-js-client-object-model-and-ui-advancements.aspx